# Buttons not fitted on layout

Tags: android

[image]I am developing a game app in Android . On PlayGame layout I am using nested Linerlayout to show Buttons (vertically )then inside that i am using Relativelayout to show side trays which are also Buttons displayed on right and left side of screen (vertical alignment ) .Problem is, all buttons are not fitted on screen size they are fitted together . Can you please suggest me how to resolve this issue? Please find my code here .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

              android:orientation="vertical"

              android:layout_width="match_parent"

              android:layout_height="match_parent"

              android:background="@drawable/background"
        >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                  android:orientation="horizontal"

                  android:layout_width="match_parent"

                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn6Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed6"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn5Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed5"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed4"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed3"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed2"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1Player2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed1"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"

                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/trayPlayer1"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnTray2"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                android:background="@drawable/pinktray"

                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/trayPlayer2"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnTray1"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                android:background="@drawable/bluetray"

                />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1Player1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/btnSeed1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2Player1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/btnSeed2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3Player1"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed3"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4Player1"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed4"

                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn5Player1"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed5"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn6Player1"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnSeed6"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:background="@drawable/pinkbowl"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnBackPlayGame"

                android:layout_width="80dp"

                android:layout_height="80dp"

                android:text="@string/btnBack"

                android:textAlignment="center"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: best way to do is using layout_weight attribute for the buttons and set every weight to 1.

Comment: There is no orientation in relativeLayout.

Comment: Does that picfture represent what you are trying to achieve or what you get, instead? How does the layout you want look like?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are trying to achieve. Do you tap a grey button for the pink buttons to show up?

Comment: i want layout like all grey and pink button should be aligned with screen size for example left and right grey and pink should be on top of brown and grey button . they are fitted with screen size

Comment: pls post desired image ..

Comment: So you want a row of  `GREY` buttons, a row of `PINK` buttons and a row with the `0` buttons?

Comment: No i want every grey top button and pink bottom buttons to get more space for example top right grey should be on top of brown and pink should be bottom of brown and so on they are not fitted good on screen size

Comment: finally i followed Opiatefuches advise to add weight to each button it solved issue please see image which i added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed  Opiatefuchs comment and assigned weight to each top row and bottom row buttons and it worked for me. Here is sample code

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn5Player2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="@string/btnSeed5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bluebowl"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```